# How to find out which object is taking space?

Tags: sql-server

I have database of size 537gb. How can I find out which object is taking space.
I executed sp_spaceused, which showed me unallocated space is 502GB and 88GB used space. How can I release unallocated space to get some free space. My HDD is getting full due to this. Please advise.

[image: Database Size]
[image: T-SQL DB Info]

Edit: I have checked via below script as well. But total UsedSpaceMB of each table is 47GB. Still I am unable to figure out how DB size is 537 GB.

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, s.Name AS SchemaName, p.rows AS RowCounts, SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB, SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB, CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
    ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID
        AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a
    ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 7 DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It appears that your database data file has empty space.

If you know for sure that the data file will **not** grow out again, you could shrink the file.

If you have to shrink, the cleanest way is doing this with `TRUNCATEONLY` so you don't move any data pages and only release the space back to the OS **if** it is possible.

You can get the data file(s) with this query, change the databasename to your database.

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = db_id('DatabaseName')
AND type_desc = 'ROWS';
```

Afterwards you could try shrinking the data page until 100GB without any movement.

```
Use [DatabaseName]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('name',102400 ,TRUNCATEONLY);
-- try to shrink until 100GB, without moving data pages
```

You can read up on shrinking date files and...

- why it sucks [here](https://littlekendra.com/2016/11/08/shrinking-sql-server-data-files-best-practices-and-why-it-sucks/)
- why it's bad for performance [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-930-data-file-shrink-does-not-affect-performance/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a script something like this to find tables and their sizes:

```
  SELECT name = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
       rows = SUM(CASE
                      WHEN index_id < 2
                      THEN row_count
                      ELSE 0
                  END), 
       reserved_mb = 8 * SUM(reserved_page_count) / 1024, 
       data_mb = 8 * SUM(CASE
                             WHEN index_id < 2
                             THEN in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
                             ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
                         END) / 1024, 
       index_mb = 8 * (SUM(used_page_count) - SUM(CASE
                                                      WHEN index_id < 2
                                                      THEN in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
                                                      ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
                                                  END)) / 1024, 
       unused_mb = 8 * SUM(reserved_page_count - used_page_count) / 1024
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id > 1024
GROUP BY object_id
ORDER BY reserved_mb DESC;
```

Comment: I have updated. Please check now.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and simplest way is using a standard report.
Right click on the database:

[image]